# Does the prerequisites to Multiattack require three different natural attacks, or just three attacks?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, natural-weapon

For example, say that a monster has a Bite attack, and two Claw attacks... A relatively common situation.

Would it qualify for Multiattack? It has three attacks (1 bite + 2 claws), after all. But do they need to be three *different* natural attacks, such as Bite/Claw/Gore?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the prerequisite is:

> Three or more natural attacks

you can take it with 1 bite and 2 claws.